# What has been going on in the atmosphere over the past couple weeks?

Tags: meteorology, atmospheric-circulation, jet-stream

First there was a once-a-century [bomb cyclone](https://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/bombogenesis.html) 2000 miles wide that froze the entire Eastern US. [Gigantic US winter storm leaves millions without power and cancels holiday plans](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2022/dec/23/us-weather-bomb-cyclone-us-christmas-latest)

Then Europe had a record breaking heat dome. Here is a new article that explains a bit about the cause. [What is causing the winter heat wave in Europe?](https://indianexpress.com/article/explained/explained-climate/what-is-causing-the-winter-heat-wave-in-europe-8359403/) It says that heat domes are caused by high pressure zones of stagnant air.

Two way bigger than normal events happened back to back. It makes me wonder if they are related? It sounds plausible that the Eastern US was cold because a lot of cold air from the arctic flowed south. If so, that air has to be replaced by warm air from the south flowing north. Did anything like this happen?

Comment: please take a look at the related Q&As many of them has links to additional information,you can click on the tabs or do a search on the top of the page too.about your question:What has been going on in the atmosphere over the past couple weeks? the answer is exactly what climate science predicted to happen=the climate is changing.

Comment: @gansub - Thank you. I have heard of it now. Interesting.

Comment: @trondhansen - Thank you. I will look. From the titles, it would not have occurred to me that they are related.

Comment: The winter is being so strange, in South Europe. We had 20ºC in December while Northamerica is frozen.

Comment: Other relevant terms to look up include teleconnections, polar vortex, polar jet stream, Arctic Oscillation, and North Atlantic Oscillation.